# counting entries, pooling over columns and returning boolean values

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, distinct

I am using Postgres 9.3 on MacOSX. I am trying to create a query function (code and example below), which counts distinct entries (`individuals`) by pooling over certain columns by using `SELECT DISTINCT ON`. This works fine. The problem arrises when I in the same function add a `CASE` statement for checking if each rows of yet another column returns `NULL` or NOT.

So, I have a table looking like this but with thousands of entries. [Here is a subset](http://i1326.photobucket.com/albums/u642/Awful-Dodger/ScreenShot2013-11-19at93404PM_zps12da3754.png) where you can see data for a particular species and method. The geographical data are of different resolution, but here I am pooling over the columns `species, method, location, larger_region` (in example, pooling over `method` is redundant) See code and output below.

```
--CODE
CREATE TABLE test_tbl (accn varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY, method TEXT, species VARCHAR(30), lat NUMERIC,       
lon NUMERIC, location TEXT, larger_region TEXT, coords BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE);

FETCH FORWARD 1 FROM test_tbl;

accn     |  method  |        species    |   lat    |    lon   |         location           | larger_region | coords 
---------+----------+-------------------+----------+----------+----------------------------+---------------+---------
EU336944 |  Isolate | Dysidea granulosa | 10.07704 | 73.63238 | Lakshadweep Islands, India | Indian EEZ    | t

CREATE TABLE test_view_tbl ( species VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, no_ind BIGINT NOT NULL, method TEXT NOT NULL, location TEXT NOT  
NULL, larger_region TEXT NOT NULL );
```

Below function produces the correct output.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_view() RETURNS SETOF test_view_tbl AS $$
SELECT DISTINCT ON (species, method, location, larger_region) species, count(species), method, location, larger_region
FROM test_tbl
GROUP BY species, method, location, larger_region
ORDER BY species;
$$ LANGUAGE sql

SELECT * FROM test_view();

       species      | no_ind | method  |               location               | larger_region 
  ------------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------+---------------
  Dysidea granulosa |      6 | Isolate | Kavaratti Island, Lakshadweep, India | Indian EEZ
  Dysidea granulosa |     13 | Isolate | Lakshadweep Islands, India           | Indian EEZ
```

Below I modify `test_view_tbl` by adding a `boolean` column `coords` and modify the code correspondingly. This checks if column `lat` is `NULL` or not, i.e. whether each entry has coordinates. However, this also screws up the above wanted result by NOT returning certain entries.

```
ALTER TABLE test_view_tbl ADD COLUMN coords BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE;

CREATE FUNCTION test_view() RETURNS SETOF test_view_tbl AS $$
SELECT DISTINCT ON (species, method, location, larger_region) species, count(species), method, location, larger_region,
CASE WHEN lat IS NULL THEN coords IS FALSE ELSE TRUE
END
FROM test_tbl 
GROUP BY species, method, location, larger_region, lat, coords
ORDER BY species;
$$ LANGUAGE sql

SELECT * FROM test_view();

      species      | no_ind | method  |               location               | larger_region | coords 
-------------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------+---------------+--------
 Dysidea granulosa |      6 | Isolate | Kavaratti Island, Lakshadweep, India | Indian EEZ    | t
 Dysidea granulosa |      3 | Isolate | Lakshadweep Islands, India           | Indian EEZ    | t
```

So, each part of the code works, but apparently not together since it returns `NULL` on 10 entries. It seems that it only counts each distinct coordinates (`lat`) within `location` `Lakshadweep Islands, India` I have tried to fix it but without success. I am hoping for some pointers.

Comment: I figure you want to aggregate on {species+location fields} How do you want the boolean `coords` to be _pooled_ in the aggregate ?

Comment: For the fields that are **not part** of the `GROUP BY` clause (or the `DISTINCT ON ...`, which is similar), the only thing you can do with them is aggregate them: take their MAX() or MIN() or there count(). (`distinct on` is a _bit_ different). What do you want to happen wrt the booleans, count the number (or proportion) of True observations in the aggregate ? Please Note: you can only make _one_ value (per aggregated group) appear in the result!

Comment: @joop: Thanks for commenting. **EDITED** Yes, you are right. I wanna pool over those fields but not over coords... even if coords are the only thing different (f / t) when the pooled fields are the same, as in the above example, I want the corresponding entries to be accounted for, thus the potential to have the same lines but with different boolean `(f / t)` values. Sorry for being unclear enough, it's too late at my end. It's mostly so I can get a feel of how many `species-location` fields I have coordinates for, for further analyses.

Comment: If you are only intersted in the records that have usable coordinates, you could simply narrow the search by means of a `WHERE lat IS NOT NULL` clause; this would omit all the latless observations from the result.

Comment: @joop: Cheers, that will do! :)